# html link or reference tag

Tags: html, tags

Is there any tag to make a link or a reference of another html tag ?

For example

```
<form>
    <label>Email</label><input name="email" type="text" /><span class="required">*</span> 
    <label>Password</label><input name="password" type="text" /><reference selector=".required" />
</form>
```

The user will actually see:

```
<form>
    <label>Email</label><input name="email" type="text" /><span class="required">*</span> 
    <label>Password</label><input name="password" type="text" /><span class="required">*</span> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 you can use the required attribute if this helps you in this specific scenario...

I'm not sure about your reference tag though!

[W3Schools Resource Here](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_required.asp)

Comment: required was just an example that's not my specific problem.

Comment: Charles - I'm not entirely sure why you would want to do this.

Comment: I use a library which has all gui element in a single container. But I would like to separate those elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery. You should be able to find a pattern (in this case the reference tag) and then replace it for an specific HTML code.